# vboxmanage modifyvm "myvm" --bioslogodisplaytime 0 still waits to press F12

Tags: virtualbox

I can successfully eliminate BIOS screen with `vboxmanage modifyvm "myvm" --bioslogodisplaytime 0`, however now still a one line message appears on the top of black and white console: `Press F12 to ...` and keeps waiting for 3-5 seconds.

It is a waste of time in my use case, how can I completely disable it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting to zero means default, which is approx. 3 seconds.
Setting to 1 means 1 msec, so that is the correct solution.